# Counting the number of elements in an XML document

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am wondering if it is possible to count the number of elements in an XML document preferably being able to fitler using something similar to `where (string)query.Attribute("attName") == att`.

Using the best of my knowledge i have tried the following but unfortunatly i can't seem to make it work.

```
                        var listElements = reader.Elements("shortlist");

                        foreach (var element in listElements)
                        {
                            XElement _xml;
                            location.Position = 0;
                            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(location);
                            _xml = XElement.Parse(file.ReadToEnd());
                            XAttribute attName = _xml.Attribute("attN");

                             if (attName.Value == att)
                            {
                                Count++;
                            }                              
                        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Silverlight are you targeting?

Comment: It is for windows phone 7 so as far as I am aware it is mainly 3 with some features of 4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that doc is an instance of `XDocument`

```
doc.Root.Descendants().Count(d => (string)d.Attribute("attName") == "value");
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce. Do I simply put `int Count = doc.Root...` to so I can use the count?

Comment: The `Where` lambda can be simplified to `d => (string)d.Attribute("attName") == "value"` and since the `Count` has an overload that takes a condition you can remove the `Where` altogether and move the lambda inside the `Count`.

Comment: I have encountered a problem with the code, if no elements with that attribute are found it returns 0, if 1 element it returns 0 and if 2 it returns 1. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: This is not my experience. Are you sure the value of the attributes is the same as the value you are comparing against?

Comment: Can you add your XML into your question, and I can take a look later?

Comment: `userExist = _doc.Root.Descendants().Count(d => (string)d.Attribute("user") == User.Text.ToLower());`

Comment: have you tried putting `ToLower()` on to the value of the attribute? i.e. `((string)d.Attribute("user")).ToLower()`

Comment: don't worry i have sussed the source of the problem, i tried a static xml and it returned the correct amount so it is a problem with my xml document in IO

Answer (score 0):

That would probably be a good application for using XPath.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333/en-us

An xpath could be "count(//*[@attName='attValue'])".

Comment: Windows Phone 7 does not support XPath since its based on Silverlight 3.

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument x = XmlDocument.Load("data.xml");   //pls excuse if i got the syntax wrong
XmlNodeList n = x.SelectNodes("//*[@attName='attValue']");
//Selects any element occuring anywhere in the document with Attribute attName='attValue'

int tadaa = n.Count;
```

Comment: `XmlDocument` not available in silverlight / Windows Phone 7

Comment: I did try this but I don't think silverlight supports the `XmlNodeList` function

Comment: Oops, sorry for double commenting, yes the correct syntax would be `XDocument` rather than `xmlDocument`